# Master/Detail Flow Data gone after click on Back Button

Tags: android, android-activity, master-detail

I am calling a Master/Detail activity in android by clicking on a button placed in another activity (UserActivity). The strange thing is, that if i click the back button in the Master/Detail activity, I loose the Data in the state of the UserActivity. It wants to execute the onCreate Method again.

If I click on the login-button in the LoginActivity where i am redirected to the UserActivitiy and i go back with the Back-Button of the "Smartphone", the username and password i typed are still there. So there i do not loose the data.

Is there a difference between the back-button of the Smartphone and the back-button at the top of the program? I am a bit confused now and i know how to persist the state of the Activity. But my question is, why i am having this behavior on the one side and on the other not.

Comment: Please share you code. Have you been using the template that also includes the `DummyContent.java` files and all that? I've recently used it for the first time and I regret not having taken a good look at the code before starting to program. The code is really under documented and you really have to take your time to figure out what data gets passed where and what's being retained

Comment: Indeed i used the template. I think it finishes the view and therefore i have to persist the data somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you will leave the question like this and don't add code:

What will probably help is checking for the amount of items that are already there. When I ran into this issue, the onStart() got called so quickly that it seemed to me that the Activity has lost the data. Actually it DID have the data, but calling onCreate/onStart (I'm in a Fragment) NULLed it.

What I did to avoid this is to check if there is a need to load items in the list. If there is, it calls a method that contains what the old onCreate/onStart did. If there is no need to load data, it will just skip the step and live with the "old" data happily for the rest of its life.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
super.onStart();

    if(DummyContent.ITEMS.size()<3){
        initializeApp();
    }

}

void initializeApp(){
    videoTitles=new ArrayList<String>();
    videoUrls=new ArrayList<String>();
    . . .
}
```